# Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation: Human readable 'definitions' section

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I want to have definitions section better generated and organized and for me this would mean to not allow depth building up in definitions, but, each class involved in the structure tree should have its own entry in the definitions section and referenced via $ref. This means that for each definition I would only have a list of properties that would either be of primitive types (string, boolean, etc.) or would be a $ref to another definition entry for another custom class. You can also see this as depth 1 definition, close to how classes are originally defined in C#.

To illustrate this via a trivial example:

```
            JSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
            schemaGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator()
            {
                DefaultRequired = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull,
                SchemaIdGenerationHandling = SchemaIdGenerationHandling.TypeName,
                SchemaLocationHandling = SchemaLocationHandling.Definitions,
                SchemaReferenceHandling = SchemaReferenceHandling.Objects,
            };
            JSchema schema = schemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(Setting));
```

Renders:

```
{
  "id": "Setting",
  "definitions": {
    "SubSetting": {
      "id": "SubSetting",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "SubSubSetting": {
          "id": "SubSubSetting",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "String": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "SubSubSetting": {
      "$ref": "SubSubSetting"
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "SubSetting": {
      "$ref": "SubSetting"
    },
    "SubSubSetting": {
      "$ref": "SubSubSetting"
    }
  }
}
```

Thus, `SubSubSetting` definition is placed inline `SubSetting` definition and later we have `SubSubSetting` defined as reference to that inline definition. That's what I want to avoid as for complex data structures it becomes really obscure and I want to provide the schema even as part of a living, auto-generated documentation based on data annotations and `JsonProperty`.

How can I accomplish this using `JSchemaGenerator`?

Maybe I shouldn't do this, but as a second very short question: Are those `$ref` syntactically correct? Shouldn't they look like `"#/definitions/SubSetting"`?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Json.NET Schema (3.0.3) has been updated to fix this issue. `SubSubSetting` will contain the full definition and not just a `$ref`.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/releases/tag/3.0.3